# jQuery Tablesorter - Disable Sort AND Filter

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I got this code from http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers.html:

```
// BONUS TIP: disable a column using jQuery data directly
// but do it before the table initializes
$("table thead th:eq(5)").data("sorter", false);
```

This works and I can add a 2nd line as shown below to disable filtering. However, I want to combine them into one line. How would I do that?

```
// I Want to combine this into the prev line   
$("table thead th:eq(5)").data("filter", false);
```

Comment: In addition to disabling sorting and filter and combining them into one line, it would be nice to also see how to disable multiple columns. For example, disable sorting and filtering in columns 5 and 7 all in a single line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TOTALLY UNTESTED** but try this

```
$("table thead th:eq(5), table thead th:eq(7)").data("sorter", false).data("filter", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add that you can combine the jQuery `data` functions:

```
$("table thead th:eq(5), table thead th:eq(7)").data({
    sorter: false,
    filter: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable sort for table cell add class in your header

```
class="sorter-false"
```

or you can add parameter in you "tablesorter" initialization:

```
headers : { 0 : { sorter: false } }
```

To Disable Filter add Parameter in Initialization

```
headers: { 0: { filter: false} }
```

DOM (Header) elements like array starting from 0

**Example**:

```
    $(".someclass").tablesorter({
        widgets : [ "filter" ],
        headers: {  0: {filter: false},
                    1: {sorter: false, filter: false},
                    2: {sorter: false}
        }
    });
```